# Django: Filter foreignkey objects by default on model

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset

I have 3 models what create a data hierarchy: Brand, Family, Car. In displaying the DetailView for the Brand, I have a table with a Brand's families (foreignkey) and in that table, I then have a property for num_cars to display the number of cars with a foreignkey back to that family.

Example:

```
Brand:Ford

Families:
Taurus 150
F150 100 
F250 0
```

This is displayed in my template as:

```
{% for family in brand.families.all %}
     {{ family }} {{ family.num_cars }}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to filter the families by the number of cars so I don't see results where there are 0 cars? I can do this in the template with:

```
{% for family in brand.families.all %}
{% if family.num_cars > 0 %}
     {{ family }} {{ family.num_cars }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

However that doesn't seem like the ideal solution. I'd like to have this in my models (if possible). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a method `get_families` to your model `Brand`

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

    def get_families(self):
        return self.families.filter(num_cars__gt = 0)
```

And then do something like this in your views.

```
{% for family in brand.get_families %}
     {{ family }} {{ family.num_cars }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This worked great - I tweaked it though. self.families.filter(cars__isnull=False)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this kind of behavour with custom managers in Django. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/
for example

```
class FamilyWithCarManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
       return super(FamilyWithCarManager, self).get_query_set().filter(num_cars__gte=0)
```

and then in your Family model:

```
class Family(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    with_cars = FamilyWithCarManager()
```

then you should be able to write a query like this:

```
Family.with_cars.all()
```

Comment: I would upvote for the recommendation to use managers, but the syntax of the filter call is wrong.

Comment: thank you for the feedback @DanielRoseman I fixed the call now.